# How to kill a process in cygwin?

Tags: process, cygwin, kill

Hi i have the following process which i cant kill:

[image: The process to be killed.]

I am running cygwin in windows xp 32 bit.

I have tried issuing the following commands:

```
/bin/kill -f 4760
/bin/kill -9 5000
kill -9 5000
kill 5000
```

When i write /bin/kill -f 4760 i get the message, 'kill: couldn't open pid 4760'.

When i write /bin/kill -9 5000 i get the message, 'kill: 5000: No such process'.

I simply don't understand why this process cant be killed. 
Since it has a WINID shouldnt it be killed by /bin/kill -f 4760?

hope someone can help thx :)

Comment: 1. start cygwin as Administrator user  2. Use the path /bin/kill (kill is a shell command in the bash shell) 3. /bin/kill -f <pid> should then work

Comment: 1. start Cygwin terminal as Administrator user  2. Use the path /bin/kill (kill is special in the bash shell) 3. /bin/kill -9 -f <pid> should then work 4. It is possible for windows processes to be in a state where they can not be killed (such as being debugged)

Answer (score 25):

The process is locked from Windows most likely. The error you are getting "couldnt open PID XXX" points to this.
To confirm try killing it with windows taskkill

```
    taskkill /PID 4760
```

Comment: When i type taskkill /PID 4760 or taskkill /PID 5000 i get the error: 'ERROR: The process "4760" not found.'

Comment: Do you see it when you do a tasklist | grep "dscli" from the windows command line?

Comment: Works on windows 7, I use `$ taskkill /F /PID <WINPID>` where `<WINPID>` is shown if I do `$ ps -a`

Answer (score 12):

Strangely, the following works in Cygwin:

```
echo PID1 PID2 PID3 | xargs kill -f
```

For example:

```
ps -W | grep WindowsPooPoo | awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do echo $line | xargs kill -f; done;
```

Comment: The important factor for me here was the `-f` argument in `kill`. Adding that stopped the "No such process" error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Different Windows programs will handle the signals that `kill` sends differently; they've never been designed to deal with them in the same way that Linux/Cygwin programs are.

The only reliable method for killing a Windows program is to use a Windows specific tool, such as Task Manager or Process Explorer.

That said, if you've not already, you may have luck with running your Cygwin terminal in administrator mode (right click on your shortcut and select "Run as administrator").

Answer (score 2):

The method presented by @Donal Tobin is correct:

`kill -f <pid>`

However, I don't need to log in as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called killall.sh with this line

```
ps -W | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do echo $line | xargs kill -f; done;
```

Then give it execute permissions.

```
chmod 777 killall.sh
```

In your .bash_profile add this line

```
alias killall="~/killall.sh"   (point it to the correct location)
```

Then you just have to type "killall [name]"

Answer (score 2):

### killall.sh - Kill by process name.

```
#/bin/bash
ps -W | grep "$1" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -f;
```

### Usage:

```
$ killall <process name>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this command **does not** work on Windows 10 in Cygwin:

```
$ kill -f 15916
bash: kill: (15916) - No such process
```

Instead of it, you can use next commands:

```
$ powershell kill -f 15916
```

```
$ netstat -ano | grep ':8080' | awk '{print $5}' | xargs powershell kill -f
```

```
$ netstat -ano | grep ':8080' | awk '{print $5}' | while read pid; do powershell kill -f $pid; done;
```

```
$ netstat -ano | grep ':8080' | awk '{sub(/\r/,"",$5) ; print $5}' | while read pid; do taskkill /F /PID $pid; done;
SUCCESS: The process with PID 15916 has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to kill a program in a .sh script like:
taskkill /F /IM notepad++.exe /T

Or to stop and leaving cygwin:
taskkill /F /IM bash.exe /T

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're not dealing with this 12 years later, but I think I have an answer that hasn't been shared yet. You can do it one of two ways (these are equivalent):

- `env kill -f -W <windows PID>`
- `/bin/kill -f -W <windows PID>`

I know there as a comment to your question similar to this, but I don't think that would've helped unless you used the `-W` flag.