# kill a process with name in windows machine

Tags: java, cygwin

I am using "**cygwin**".
I know '**TASKKILL**' allows to kill process. But it wont allow to kill by process name. I tried **psKill** , but it is giving error as not recognized. Some one please help me.If i want to kill 'test.py', how to do it. TASKKILL will kill all the python process running.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: It is a programming question.To kill a process using java code.Cygwin is used to connect to windows machine.

Comment: Please hit the [edit] link above and make it clear in your question *exactly* what it is that you are trying to do, and also add appropriate tags (e.g. `java`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is related to your Cygwin environment only -- as opposed to the larger Windows process environment -- there are standard *nix type tools available in the Cygwin distribution to manage this.  Processes are identified by unique ID numbers that you can kill with the `kill` command from your Cygwin shell prompt.  Run the `ps` command to see a list of all processes currently running from Cygwin.

If your question is more involved than this, you might give this post a look:

[How to kill a process in cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877652/how-to-kill-a-process-in-cygwin)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know taskkill can be used if you know pid. I am trying to automate process of killing a process and restarting it through java program. So I should know how to get PID to a variable and use that with taskkill .
Let me explain it with an example. Let’s say I have a python ‘test.py’ script running. I need a command which kill ‘test.py’ not all python process running in the machine. If I use _taskkill /f /im python.exe_, it will kill all python process which I don’t want. Or should know how to get PID of ‘test.py’ ,pass it to a variable and use it with taskkill PID.